# How to set the type of a pyqtSignal (variable of class X) that takes a X instance as argument

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, pyqt5

I have a pyqtSignal as a class variable and I want its argument to be an instance of that class. How can I declare the type of the argument when I create the signal?

```
class MyClass(QWidget):
    my_signal = pyqtSignal(?)

    (...)

    def emit_signal(self):
        self.my_signal.emit(self)
```

I know that `pyqtSignal(object)` would work but I was wondering if there was a sort of `__class__` at class-variable level.

Another question: is there a difference between `pyqtSignal(MyClass)`, `pyqtSignal(QWidget)` (parent class) or `pyqtSignal(object)`? Performance? I'm asking this question because the types of slot parameters don't seem to matter when we declare them with the `@pyqtSlot` decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the Python interpreter interprets `my_signal = pyqtSignal(...)`, the class name is not known to it yet, the class body is created first then it will be assigned to the module variable called `MyClass`. So the only way to do this is after the class has been defined, and before any attempt is made to access the signal object. This means one of the following two options *might* work (it depends on how pyqtSignal and QObject work, I can't try it out at this moment):

1. At module level, after class:

   ```
   class MyClass(QObject):
       def __init__(self, ...):
   ...

   MyClass.my_signal = pyqtSignal(MyClass)
   ```
2. In the init, guarding against re-creation:

   ```
   class MyClass(QObject):
       def __init__(self, ...):
           if not hasattr(self, 'my_signal'):
               MyClass.my_signal = pyqtSignal(MyClass)
   ```